# Android: award free in-app-purchase items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I would like to give some in-app-purchase items for free to some users.

Is there a way to do this without setting up my own server transaction verification?

Maybe somehow through the Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without setting up my own server transaction verification?

No there is no way on Google Play Developer console which you are looking. You either have to manage this stuff from any other payment gateway and do transaction stuff from your end to achieve this.